# When updating to Drupal 8.9.15, I get the following Behat JS error on Probo. No idea what this means. Thoughts?

Tags: behat

--- Failed hooks:
29
30    AfterScenario # FeatureContext::cleanUsers()
31      unknown error: session deleted because of page crash
32      from unknown error: cannot determine loading status
33      from tab crashed
34        (Session info: chrome=90.0.4430.93)
35        (Driver info: chromedriver=90.0.4430.24 (4c6d850f087da467d926e8eddb76550aed655991-refs/branch-heads/4430@{#429}),platform=Linux 4.15.0-51-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
36      Command duration or timeout: 102 milliseconds
37      Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:37:03'
38      System info: host: '5b4b50a6dced', ip: '172.17.0.15', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.15.0-51-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_292'
39      Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
40      Capabilities [{mobileEmulationEnabled=false, timeouts={implicit=0, pageLoad=300000, script=30000}, hasTouchScreen=false, platform=LINUX, acceptSslCerts=false, goog:chromeOptions={debuggerAddress=localhost:45509}, acceptInsecureCerts=false, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, setWindowRect=true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=ignore, applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=90.0.4430.24 (4c6d850f087da467d926e8eddb76550aed655991-refs/branch-heads/4430@{#429}), userDataDir=/tmp/.com.google.Chrome.u9Jse4}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, strictFileInteractability=false, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, version=90.0.4430.93, browserConnectionEnabled=false, proxy={}, nativeEvents=true, locationContextEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators=true}]
41      Session ID: a7e935864c137f001f5cb4ed9a18a560
42      *** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//html/descendant-or-self::body[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' logged-in ')] | //html/descendant-or-self::body[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' user-logged-in ')]} (WebDriver\Exception\UnknownError)

Comment: seems that the page crashed. happens often? what selenium version are you using?

Comment: also what does this do? FeatureContext::cleanUsers()